# YouTube iFrame API “setPlaybackQuality” not working

Tags: api, iframe, youtube

YouTube iFrame API “setPlaybackQuality” not working.i want to change video qulity to lowest.but i cant change it by the api.i used player.setPlaybackQuality('small').it not worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="change_quality">Change Quality</button>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: '6LV3JdR5aZw',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
                });
            }
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                
                
                
            }
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    $("#change_quality").click(function() {
                    event.target.playVideo();
                      
                var d=player.getPlaybackQuality()
                console.log("before");
                console.log(d);
                player.setPlaybackQuality('small')
                var v=player.getPlaybackQuality()
                console.log("after");
                console.log(v);
                
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

it is not working in youtube demo also
[Demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)